# SQL get Max Column value for each Row

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Sample Table : MyTable1

```
Col1    |    Col2     |     Col3
   3           10            5
  10           9             40
   1           2             6
```

The Output must be:

```
NewColumn
    10
    40
     6
```

As you can see, I just need to get the highest value from  each row..

Is it possible by just using a sql select query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the MS Access function `IIF()`

```
IIF(condition, valueiftrue, valueiffalse)
```

> condition is the value that you want to test.
>
> valueiftrue is the value that is returned if condition evaluates to
>   TRUE.
>
> valueiffalse is the value that is returned if condition evaluates to
>   FALSE.

so your query would be

```
SELECT IIf(C12 > Col3, C12, Col3) as newColumn
FROM
(
    select IIF(Col1 > Col2,  Col1,  Col2) as C12, Col3
    from mytable1
) x
```

Comment: +1 but you could just nest the IIFs in each other. Or does MS Access forbid this particular kind of nesting?

Comment: @AndriyM Yes you can nest the IIFs and I initially had it written that way but I thought this was easier to read.

Comment: Actually, what I had in mind was incorrect, because I had (dis)missed the `C12` in the condition and thought you'd need to replace *only* the `TRUE`-term `C12`. You are quite right to have decided to write out the IIFs like this.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this would work in MS Access (can't verify myself, I'm afraid):

```
SELECT
  (
    SELECT MAX(Col)
    FROM (
      SELECT Col1 AS Col UNION ALL
      SELECT Col2        UNION ALL
      SELECT Col3
    ) s
  ) AS NewColumn
FROM yourtable
```

This works in *the other* family of database products by the same vendor, so I thought they might just happen to have added support for this in MS Access too.

Answer (score 0):

Example which works:

**Table1:**

```
Col - Text
Col1 - Number
Col2 - Number
Col3 - Number
Col4 - Number
```

**Data:**

```
col; col1; col2; col3; col4;
a;      1;    4;    6;    7;
b;      3;   66;   23;  235;
c;     34;  634;   11;   23;
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT Col, Max(colx) AS MaxOfColx
FROM 
(
SELECT Col, Col1 AS Colx From Table1 UNION ALL
SELECT Col, Col2 AS Colx From Table1 UNION ALL
SELECT Col, Col3 AS Colx From Table1 UNION ALL
SELECT Col, Col4 AS Colx From Table1
)
group by Col
```

**Result:**

```
Col; MaxOfColx
 a;          7
 b;        235
 c;        634
```

This will work for as many columns as you need.

Comment: Pro tip: Use the handy code formatting features when answering a question and you don't have to write HTML yourself. Also note, that there's already an accepted answer :)